# Getting only last item of List View

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing, android-adapter, android-listfragment

I've parsing a XML inside a `ListFragment`, it's working fine but the `OnListItemClick` is only throwing the last item, I've searched but I did not found anything that matches my case.

This is inside `onPostExecute`:

```
        XMLDOMParser parser = new XMLDOMParser();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
        Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        newss = new ArrayList<News>();
        news = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            news = new News();
            Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            news.setId(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            news.setDate(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
            news.setTitle(parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            news.setDescription(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            newss.add(news);
        }

        listViewAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newss);
        getListView().setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        pDialog.dismiss();
```

`OnItemClick` that is inside the same fragment:

```
`@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List: "+news.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleNewsActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_ID, news.getId());
    in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, news.getDate());
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, news.getTitle());
    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, news.getDescription());
    startActivity(in);
}`
```

My `NewsAdapter`:

`public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    List<News> newss;
    public NewsAdapter (Activity context, List<News> newss) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newss = newss;
    }`

```
// private View Holder class
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvNewsDate;
    TextView TvNewsTitle;
}

public int getCount() {
    return newss.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return newss.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return newss.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvNewsDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsDate);
        holder.TvNewsTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsTitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    News newss = (News) getItem(position);

    holder.tvNewsDate.setText(newss.getDate());
    holder.TvNewsTitle.setText(newss.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

}`

`ImageView` with `setOnClickListner` inside my other adapter with the same problem:

`holder.ivGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + parkCoordinates);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                context.startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        });`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MikeM. added, thank you

Comment: I notice that even on my other adapter (almost equal) it's happening the same inside the adapter when I set `setOnClickListener` for a `ImageView`. Can you please make an example? I'm a bit noob.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you check my last code please? I'm not getting the position because it's supposed to work fine right? Since it's inside the adapter. It displays all information properly except this clickListener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121737/discussion-between-filipeos-and-mike-m).

Comment: @MikeM. I've placed this ( `holder.ivGPS.setTag(position);` ) right before the setOnClickListener but is not working.. Sorry, can  you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try 
news = newss.get(position)
and Use this in you onListItemClick it may work..

```
  `@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  news = newss.get(position)
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleNewsActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_ID, news.getId());
    in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, news.getDate());
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, news.getTitle());
    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, news.getDescription());
    startActivity(in);
}`
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you only help me with the last code I've placed please? I've commented to MikeM what is not working. I

Comment: Sorry for delay, you can use same news = newss.get(position) in your other adapter. you can get postion from getview method and use value from that position.

Comment: can you make an example please?

Comment: get parkCoordinates by using position from getview method and in onclick  pass this.. into google navigation.. Post your second adapter

Comment: it's on the same adapter, I've placed it on my question, on the bottom, thank you!

Comment: Basically I can't access the position inside the `setOnClickListener`, I've spent hours on this and I can't find a reason.. If I `Toast` for example `news.getId()` it will work but If I request `news.getTitle()` it wont.

Comment: You can do as News news = newss.get(position);       and in your click lisner get news.getDate();